# Переменные js и атрибуты data-*

Tags: javascript, атрибуты

Имеются кнопки. Имеются переменные, каждая из которых соответсвует каждой кнопке - она принимает значение true при нажатии, остальные принимают false.

Для каждого события писать то, что там уже есть слишком громоздско, тем более в оригинале кнопок больше, чем 3.
Для автоматизации этого пришло на ум ввести каждой кноке по data-*, совпадающей с именем переменной. А вот как технически найти "близнец" среди переменной, и установить ему true (например one и one ), ПРИ ЭТОМ остальным (в данном случе two и three) присвоить false (если до нажатия 1 были другие нажатия)(возможно, для второго надо заводить массив переменных)

Если с data-* идея плохая, готова к другим вариантам
https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/tbL77s59/
Заранее спасибо

```
$('#btn-1').click(function() {
    var name = this.dataset.name; 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  one: false,
  two: false,
  three: false
};
console.log(data);

$('.buttons').click(function() {
  for (var key in data) {
    data[key] = false;
  }
  data[this.dataset.name] = true;
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="buttons" style="display:inline;" data-name="one">1</button>
<button class="buttons" style="display:inline;" data-name="two">2</button>
<button class="buttons" style="display:inline;" data-name="three">3</button>
```